# Python 3.6.x / Django 2.0.x uuids in paths failig

Tags: django, python-3.x

Python: 3.6.3  //  Django: 2.0.2

I am trying two new things at one time.  Class Based Views and using UUIDs as "account numbers".

`urls.py` is:

```
    from django.urls import path, re_path

    from .views.index import *
    from .views import profile

    urlpatterns = [
        re_path(r'^$', index.IndexDetailView.as_view(), name='index'),
        path('Members', index.IndexDetailView.as_view(), name='index'),
        path('Members/Profile/<uuid:account_number>/', profile.ProfileDetailView.as_view(), name='profile-detail'),
        path('Members/Profile/<uuid:account_number>/edit', profile.edit),
        path('Members/Profile/create', profile.create),
    ]
```

"Profile" is an extension of the "User" model.  The Profile includes an account_number field:

```
    account_number = models.UUIDField(
        max_length=32,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False,
        unique=True,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
    )
```

The ``DetailView` I am trying out is:

```
    class ProfileDetailView(DetailView):
        model = Profile
        pk_url_kwarg = "account_number"
        template_name = 'Members/profile2.html'

        @verified_email_required
        def get_object(self, queryset=None):
            queryset = self.get_queryset() if queryset is None else queryset
            profile = get_object_or_404(queryset, account_number=self.kwargs['account_number'])
            # profile = super().get_object()
            return profile

        @verified_email_required
        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['form_readonly'] = True
            return context
```

There is a "partial" view/template that displayes the Profile info.  It contains an "Edit" button that looks like:

```
    <div id="profileDetails" class="profileDetails">
        <h4>Account Holder Details:</h4>

        <table class="profileDetails text-left">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <td>{{ profile.last_name }},
                        {{ profile.first_name }}{% if profile.middle_name %} {{ profile.middle_name }}{% endif %}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <td>{% if profile.address1 %}
                        {{ profile.address1 }}<br>
                    {% endif %}
                        {{ profile.address2 }}<br>
                        {{ profile.city }}, {{ profile.state }} {{ profile.zip }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                    <td>{{ profile.phone }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <td>{{ request.user.email }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Birthday</th>
                    <td>{{ profile.birthdate }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="smallText">{% if profile.dateModified %}
                        Last Modified
                    {% else %}
                        Date Created
                    {% endif %}</th>
                    <td class="smallText">{% if profile.dateModified %}
                        {{ profile.dateModified }}
                    {% else %}
                        {{ profile.dateCreated }}
                    {% endif %}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" class="centerText">
                        <form class="inlineBlock" method="get" action="/Members/Profile/{{ profile.account_number }}/edit">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <button id="profileEditButton" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">Edit</button>
                        </form>
                        <button id="profileDeleteButton" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger inlineBlock">Delete
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

When I run this in `DEBUG` mode I get the error:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/Members/Profile/7fb2fb24-5ebd-43a4-a237-4ad39618719d/edit?csrfmiddlewaretoken=...
Django Version: 2.0.2
Exception Type: ValidationError
Exception Value:    
["'169741278071848279598077364489084760477' is not a valid UUID."]
Exception Location: C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py in to_python, line 2368
Python Executable:  C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.3
```

Do I need to init the uuid DB field differently?  Should I access it differently?  Remove the hyphens?

Actually, removing the hyphens in the path has `urls.py` fail.  The error is that `The current path, Members/Profile/7fb2fb245ebd43a4a2374ad39618719d/edit, didn't match any of these`.  Where "these" is the list of url paths above.

What am I missing?

**Traceback from Windows, same from linux**

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/Members/Profile/7fb2fb24-5ebd-43a4-a237-4ad39618719d/edit?csrfmiddlewaretoken=yblBLKot54xoB0Laq7fBVIeZARmvWFq7IY6mZ23XrjxbmyU0xZ55VTOqImCmBqvc

Django Version: 2.0.2
Python Version: 3.6.3
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django_extensions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'allauth.socialaccount',
 'auditlog',
 'widget_tweaks',
 'Members.apps.MembersConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'auditlog.middleware.AuditlogMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in to_python
  2363.                 return uuid.UUID(value)

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\uuid.py" in __init__
  137.             hex = hex.replace('urn:', '').replace('uuid:', '')

During handling of the above exception ('int' object has no attribute 'replace'), another exception occurred:

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\allauth\account\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  32.             return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:/Users/Me/PycharmProjects/MyProject/MyApp\Members\views\profile.py" in edit
  77.         profile = Profile.objects.get(account_number=int(account_number))

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in get
  397.         num = len(clone)

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in __len__
  254.         self._fetch_all()

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _fetch_all
  1179.             self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in __iter__
  53.         results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1051.             sql, params = self.as_sql()

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in as_sql
  459.                 where, w_params = self.compile(self.where) if self.where is not None else ("", [])

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in compile
  391.             sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection)

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\where.py" in as_sql
  80.                 sql, params = compiler.compile(child)

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in compile
  391.             sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection)

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py" in as_sql
  161.         rhs_sql, rhs_params = self.process_rhs(compiler, connection)

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py" in process_rhs
  260.         return super().process_rhs(compiler, connection)

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py" in process_rhs
  93.             return self.get_db_prep_lookup(value, connection)

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py" in get_db_prep_lookup
  187.             [get_db_prep_value(value, connection, prepared=True)]

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in get_db_prep_value
  2354.             value = self.to_python(value)

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in to_python
  2368.                     params={'value': value},

Exception Type: ValidationError at /Members/Profile/7fb2fb24-5ebd-43a4-a237-4ad39618719d/edit
Exception Value: ["'169741278071848279598077364489084760477' is not a valid UUID."]
```

Comment: You'll need to post the full traceback - it's impossible to tell what validation is failing. Although I note that you almost certainly shouldn't be using `@verified_email_required`, whatever that is, on those methods.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: added traceback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `int(account_number)` will convert your uuid.uuid4() object to an integer that will break `UUIDField` validation and will raise a `ValidationError`.

```
>>> uuid.uuid4()
UUID('e05b17de-061b-4609-b2b5-b84b0168a9dd')
>>> int(uuid.uuid4())
277437837159711504976083722802700941846
```

so you do not need to convert it to an integer.

```
File "C:/Users/Me/PycharmProjects/MyProject/MyApp\Members\views\profile.py" in edit
  77.         profile = Profile.objects.get(account_number=int(account_number))
```

Comment: Doh! how did I miss that, Thank you